# How to make superclass querysets return subclass objects? Or downcast the superclass queryset to a subclass list?

Tags: python, django, web

I'm working in a django project which I need to list two different models in the same view ordered by date. In order to achieve that I used inheritance to be able to get them all into a generic queryset. My models are:

```
class Publication(models.model):
    title = models.CharField(max_lengh = 200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default = datetime.now)
    headline = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def say_hello(self):
        return

class New(Publication):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
    source = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    url = '/news/'

    def say_hello(self):
        return "Hello New!!!"

class Opinion(Publication):
    writer = models.ForeignKey(Writer)
    style = .models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=(('txt', 'Text'), ('glr', 'Galery')))
    url = '/opinions/'

    def say_hello(self):
        return "Hello Opinion!!!"
```

I'm trying to call the subclass method while iterating through the Publication QuerySet like this:

```
publications = Publications.objects.all().order_by('-pub_date')
for pub in publications:
    pub.say_hello()
    url = pub.url
```

The problem is that my QuerySet is returning Publication objects, so I can't access child attributes and methods, obviously cus I'm dealing with Publication objects.  Shouldn't The fact that I've set Publication as an abstract class, avoid the possibility of dealing with Publication objects?. Shouldn't they be prevented from being instantiated? Is there any option for perform perform a QuerySet in Publication class and return a list with child objects?

If no. How would you guys go around this situation? I could really use some tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like it might be appropriate to use multi-table inheritance and django polymorphic:

Multi-table inheritance: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance

Django polymorphic: http://django-polymorphic.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Multi-table inheritance in django allows you to have a base model/table which has your base fields.  Your subclasses then define the extended fields which are put in their own tables.  When you fetch records with querysets from any of the subclasses, you'll get information for each record from both the base model/table and the subclass model/table.

In order to fetch records using the base model's queryset, and get an instance of the appropriate subclass for each result, one option is django polymorphic.  I've used it before and it works pretty well.  It definitely has its limitations but I'd give it a shot.

Comment: Django polymorphic seems great. The problem is that I already have a database populated. I tried to run south migration but polymorphic_ctype_id is NULL. Is there a trick for apply django-polymorphic in a already existing populated db?

Comment: Well, I've never done that before but I bet it could be done.  I can't give any great advice, but I'd suggest starting by making a test app with polymorphic models, migrating the database, and inspecting the way that polymorphic structures its tables.  Most of the work would probably be in updating any models referring to your two old models since the id column values will have to change.

Comment: It worked! The django-polymorphic module adds a polymorphic_ctype field to the model which reffers to a instance of from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType. I just did a for through all my child models added its contentType object and saved it.

Comment: It worked! The django-polymorphic module adds a polymorphic_ctype field to the model which reffers to a instance of from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

Comment: @Mauricio Great!  Glad to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

Each Publication instance should have either a 'new' attribute or a 'opinion' attribute pointing to one of the two subclasses respectively. Be aware that each instance has only one of this attributes so maybe it's better to try...except access to them.

Comment: You can edit your original question to include more information if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I will put the code for my solution here which I achieved thanks to @David answer.

As suggested for David, I used django-polymorphic, which is great and simple. But the fact that I already had a populated database, made things a bit complicated. Nothing hard to fix.

First thing I did was to migrate the database with `south` in order to add the new field (`polymorphic_ctype`) to my parent model (no field is added to the subclasses).

Then, I used the following code in django shell mode on terminal. (`python manage.py shell`)

```
from jornal.models import Publication, New, Opinion
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

ctype_opinion = ContentType.objects.get(model = 'opinion', app_label = 'jornal')
ctype_new = ContentType.objects.get(model = 'new', app_label = 'jornal')
opinions = Opinion.objects.non_polymorphic().all()
news = New.objects.non_polymorphic().all()

for new in news:
    new.polymorphic_ctype = ctype_new
    new.save()

for opinion in opinions:
    opinion.polymorphic_ctype = ctype_opinion
    opinion.save()
```